# SQL GROUP BY query issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
DriverNumber; DriverName; CarNumber; DriverConditions; LogonTime; VehicleID
```

this table has an entry for each LogonTime for each DriverNumber, and a driver can logon to different vehicles.

for example:

```
93070495    Mehar   189 Parcel, V, Wheelchair, M50, Special, Animal, COD P...       Jan  2 2014 07:40:26:197AM  1029
93070495    Mehar   189 Parcel, V, Wheelchair, M50, Special, Animal, COD P...       Jan  7 2014 08:09:50:097AM  1029
25184313    Kerry   895 Parcel, Cheques, V, Wheelchair, Special, Animal, C...       Jan  3 2014 05:00:26:600PM  970
```

what i essentially want to do is show how many times a DriverNumber logs into each car.

this is what i have done so far:

```
SELECT DriverNumber, DriverName, CarNumber, DriverConditions, LogonTime, 
    count(DriverNumber) as DriverCount 
FROM SilverDrivers 
WHERE DriverNumber > 0
GROUP BY CarNumber
```

This gives me close to what i am after, but it only shows one CarNumber per DriverNumber. eg:

```
DRIVER HDL | DRIVER NAME | CAR NUMBER | DRIVER CONDITIONS | NUMBER OF LOGONS
98749492   | Manpreet    | 3          | Parcel            | 10
32176467   | Mark        | 19         | Wheelchair        | 7
92173581   | Varinder    | 46         | Parcel            | 1
```

what i want it to look like is:

```
DRIVER HDL | DRIVER NAME | CAR NUMBER | DRIVER CONDITIONS | NUMBER OF LOGONS
98749492   | Manpreet    | 3          | Parcel            | 7
98749492   | Manpreet    | 12         | Parcel            | 3
32176467   | Mark        | 19         | Wheelchair        | 4
32176467   | Mark        | 214        | Wheelchair        | 3
92173581   | Varinder    | 46         | Parcel            | 1
```

Comment: Dude, get rid of comma separated values in columns. Read about database normalization. Will spare yourself a lot of headaches...

Comment: something like : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6be24f/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should also group by driver number to get the count you want. Also, add all the other columns to your `GROUP BY` clause and remove columns that wouldn't be unique from `SELECT` (I left only `DriverName` as I assume it's always the same for one `DriverNumber`).

```
SELECT DriverNumber, DriverName, CarNumber, count(*) as DriverCount 
FROM SilverDrivers 
WHERE DriverNumber > 0
GROUP BY DriverNumber, DriverName, CarNumber
```

Comment: Please stop encouraging non ANSI standard `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Thanks's for reminding, very true! I corrected my answer.

Answer (score -5):

You want either

```
GROUP BY DriverNumber, CarNumber
```

or

```
GROUP BY CarNumber, DriverNumber
```

Comment: Please stop encouraging non ANSI standard `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO  And how, pray tell, would *you* get the same result without using `GROUP BY`?  Let's see it.  I dare you to come up with a way that doesn't require 10x (or more) time.  "ANSI standard" is not like "WC3 standard" -- it's an ideal for how a relational database might be created.  MYSQL does not follow that ideal.

Comment: Probably using `DISTINCT`. Just because MySQL doesn't follow it, doesn't mean you should encourage that users of it to not follow it. If this user ever moves to an ANSI standard DBMS, they're going to wonder why @spsc_tech told them to use `GROUP BY` incorrectly.

Comment: "Probably" is not a convincing argument.  Plus, I can't find anywhere that says `GROUP BY` is non-ANSI.  http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/sql/0596004818/4dot-sql-functions/id3751217 clearly says it must be used in certain cases.  http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/answer/ISO-ANSI-SQL-and-the-GROUP-BY-clause is obviously about using it in ANSI/ISO.

Comment: Post me a link to some article or textbook that explains why I shouldn't be using `GROUP BY`, and post an answer to this question that solves the issue as well or better than `GROUP BY`, and only then will I be able to listen to what you are saying.

Comment: Nobody said not to use GROUP BY. They said to not use GROUP BY the way you're suggesting it (`SELECT a,b,c,MAX() ... GROUP BY a,b;`) - which is non-standard and only supported in MySQL and only when a certain setting is set a certain way (`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`).

Comment: @spsc_tech We're talking about `GROUP BY` in MySQL. [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: The point is that MySQL's implementation of `GROUP BY` is not ANSI standard. It's not "don't use `GROUP BY`", the point is "don't use non-standards-compliant variants of `GROUP BY`".

Comment: [Example of ANSI standard `GROUP BY` usage](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26a4f/1); [Example of MySQL's `GROUP BY` usage](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26a4f/1)

Comment: That's like saying, "In Latin, you have to conjugate verbs like XYZ which is difficult, but in Spanish, you have the new option to conjugate them like ZYX which is easy, so it's wrong of Spanish speakers to use ZYX because they improved on Latin."  I see no logic in not using a tool that is an express improvement.

Comment: @spsc_tech Your analogy is meaningless; please refer to the examples I've given.

Comment: The problem with your analogy is that Spanish doesn't have a setting to turn that conjugation option off. Your code won't work when `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled, which will probably be the case in any shop that cares at all about SQL standards or about writing queries against more than one platform. Never mind that imbalanced SELECT / GROUP BY sets will most likely confuse anyone who comes across them if they learned SQL the right way.

Comment: I'm still waiting for you to post an answer to this question that gives the same results as the "non-standard" query.  The other answer posted does not give the same result because it does not return all of the desired columns.  I am not asking this idly -- I have hundreds of database calls in my business's web store, and surely some of them are non-standard, but I'm not going to change them if it means I have to do a second query to get the other columns that are not aggregated.

Comment: You don't need a second query, just aggregate them or include them in the GROUP BY clause. Simple as that.

Comment: One of the columns returned in the original query is `LogonTime` and I'm guessing (from its name) it is unique for each record. You cannot have it meaningfully returned when you're grouping in the way you (and I suggest).

Comment: I have the feeling that the guy didn't give us everything in his examples because his example tables are different from the query. Where does Number of Logons come from but from some COUNT we don't see?  Anyway, I am reading http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html which is much more informative on the subject than tiny comments on someone else's question.  Thanks for pointing me in this direction.